# Issue with implementing Youtube API v3 on Python for Django (error: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'video')

Tags: python, django, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to upload a file to my youtube channel using the [youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python)

This is my upload action

**videos/views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    """
    Upload video
    :param request:
    """

    context = RequestContext(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # do the following
        form_upload = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form_upload.is_valid():
            uploaded_video = form_upload.save(commit=True)
            uploaded_video.category = 23
            uploaded_video.privacyStatus = 'public'

            # send this file to youtube
            initialize_upload(uploaded_video.file_on_server.path, uploaded_video)

            messages.success(request, 'Video saved.')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Ooops.')

    else:
        form_upload = VideoForm(instance=request.user)

    context_dict = {'form_upload': form_upload}

    return render_to_response('videos/upload.html', context_dict, context)
```

And this is the Python example [provide by google.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python#upload_a_video)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import httplib
import httplib2
import os
import random
import sys
import time

from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.tools import argparser, run_flow


# Explicitly tell the underlying HTTP transport library not to retry, since
# we are handling retry logic ourselves.
httplib2.RETRIES = 1

# Maximum number of times to retry before giving up.
MAX_RETRIES = 10

# Always retry when these exceptions are raised.
RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS = (httplib2.HttpLib2Error, IOError, httplib.NotConnected,
  httplib.IncompleteRead, httplib.ImproperConnectionState,
  httplib.CannotSendRequest, httplib.CannotSendHeader,
  httplib.ResponseNotReady, httplib.BadStatusLine)

# Always retry when an apiclient.errors.HttpError with one of these status
# codes is raised.
RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES = [500, 502, 503, 504]

# The CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE variable specifies the name of a file that contains
# the OAuth 2.0 information for this application, including its client_id and
# client_secret. You can acquire an OAuth 2.0 client ID and client secret from
# the Google Developers Console at
# https://console.developers.google.com/.
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
# For more information about using OAuth2 to access the YouTube Data API, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication
# For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, see:
#   https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE = "client_secrets.json"

# This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
# authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

# This variable defines a message to display if the CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE is
# missing.
MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE = """
WARNING: Please configure OAuth 2.0

To make this sample run you will need to populate the client_secrets.json file
found at:

   %s

with information from the Developers Console
https://console.developers.google.com/

For more information about the client_secrets.json file format, please visit:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_client_secrets
""" % os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                                   CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE))

VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES = ("public", "private", "unlisted")


def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE,
    scope=YOUTUBE_UPLOAD_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  return build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))

def initialize_upload(youtube, options):
  tags = None
  if options.keywords:
    tags = options.keywords.split(",")

  body=dict(
    snippet=dict(
      title=options.title,
      description=options.description,
      tags=tags,
      categoryId=options.category
    ),
    status=dict(
      privacyStatus=options.privacyStatus
    )
  )

  # Call the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part=",".join(body.keys()),
    body=body,
    # The chunksize parameter specifies the size of each chunk of data, in
    # bytes, that will be uploaded at a time. Set a higher value for
    # reliable connections as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    # value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    #
    # Setting "chunksize" equal to -1 in the code below means that the entire
    # file will be uploaded in a single HTTP request. (If the upload fails,
    # it will still be retried where it left off.) This is usually a best
    # practice, but if you're using Python older than 2.6 or if you're
    # running on App Engine, you should set the chunksize to something like
    # 1024 * 1024 (1 megabyte).
    media_body=MediaFileUpload(options.file, chunksize=-1, resumable=True)
  )

  resumable_upload(insert_request)

# This method implements an exponential backoff strategy to resume a
# failed upload.
def resumable_upload(insert_request):
  response = None
  error = None
  retry = 0
  while response is None:
    try:
      print "Uploading file..."
      status, response = insert_request.next_chunk()
      if 'id' in response:
        print "Video id '%s' was successfully uploaded." % response['id']
      else:
        exit("The upload failed with an unexpected response: %s" % response)
    except HttpError, e:
      if e.resp.status in RETRIABLE_STATUS_CODES:
        error = "A retriable HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status,
                                                             e.content)
      else:
        raise
    except RETRIABLE_EXCEPTIONS, e:
      error = "A retriable error occurred: %s" % e

    if error is not None:
      print error
      retry += 1
      if retry > MAX_RETRIES:
        exit("No longer attempting to retry.")

      max_sleep = 2 ** retry
      sleep_seconds = random.random() * max_sleep
      print "Sleeping %f seconds and then retrying..." % sleep_seconds
      time.sleep(sleep_seconds)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  argparser.add_argument("--file", required=True, help="Video file to upload")
  argparser.add_argument("--title", help="Video title", default="Test Title")
  argparser.add_argument("--description", help="Video description",
    default="Test Description")
  argparser.add_argument("--category", default="22",
    help="Numeric video category. " +
      "See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list")
  argparser.add_argument("--keywords", help="Video keywords, comma separated",
    default="")
  argparser.add_argument("--privacyStatus", choices=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES,
    default=VALID_PRIVACY_STATUSES[0], help="Video privacy status.")
  args = argparser.parse_args()

  if not os.path.exists(args.file):
    exit("Please specify a valid file using the --file= parameter.")

  youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
  try:
    initialize_upload(youtube, args)
  except HttpError, e:
    print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

**But I get the following error message:**

```
  AttributeError at /videos/upload
'unicode' object has no attribute 'videos'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/videos/upload
Django Version: 1.7.2
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'unicode' object has no attribute 'videos'
Exception Location: /home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/humor15.com/src/videos/upload_video.py in initialize_upload, line 108
Python Executable:  /home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/humor15.com/src',
 '/home/ymorin007/Softwares/pycharm-4.0/helpers/pydev',
 '/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/humor15.com/src',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 21 Jan 2015 15:33:22 -0400
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view

/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/ymorin007/.virtualenvs/humor15/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py in _wrapped_view
                return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/humor15.com/src/videos/views.py in upload
            initialize_upload(uploaded_video.file_on_server.path, uploaded_video) ...
▶ Local vars
/home/ymorin007/workspace/sites/humor15.com/src/videos/upload_video.py in initialize_upload
  insert_request = youtube.videos().insert( ...
▶ Local vars
```

I couldn't find any explanation for this error.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

BTW. This is my 1st experience with Python and youtube Data API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traceback is telling you that you're trying to call an unsupported method on a unicode (string) object. That appears to be the result of this line in views.py:

```
initialize_upload(uploaded_video.file_on_server.path, uploaded_video)
```

Here's what the example shows:

```
 youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)
 try:
    initialize_upload(youtube, args)
```

It appears you'll want to pass this function an instance of your service object, not the path of an uploaded video.

Comment: Excuse my stupidity but can you give me a hint about what should be the service object I should pass. Thanks.

Comment: In the example, it's youtube = get_authenticated_service(args). In the example, args is populated from the command line that calls the script. You'll need to look closely at the code under if __ name __ == '__ main __' to see what kind of args you'll need to pass in here.

Comment: I'm not sure about the 1st argument for initialize_upload(youtube, options): I've added the path to the file but probably it needs to go with the options. But in that case what is the argument youtube? Also I've looked at the args under the __name__ and I've provided them all.

Comment: It comes from the line just above it in the example: youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)

Comment: But what argument do I need to send from my view.py for the youtube arg. As of now I have the following: initialize_upload(uploaded_video.file_on_server.path, uploaded_video)

Comment: Yes... I see what you have. You need to pass these arguments to get_authenticated_service() and then pass the results into initialize_upload(). You don't pass a copy of the file, the path to the file is one of the arguments passed to get_authenticated_service(). Again, the naming and elements you need to provide is demonstrated in the code under `if __name__ == '__main__'` in the example.